# How Can I Extract a Substring in WHERE Clause of <CFQUERY>?

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

Is it possible to extract a substring in the WHERE clause in ColdFusion of either  or in a Query of Queries?  As an example, I am trying to use the following query to find all email addresses with the domain "comcast.net" (i.e. everything after the "@" in the email address).  I am querying an MS-Access database table.

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="membership">
      SELECT email_address
      FROM tblMembers
      WHERE MID(email_address, INSTR(email_address, '@') + 1) = 'comcast.net'
</cfquery>
```

If I attempt this as a query, I get the error message "[Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression."

If I attempt it as a Query of Queries, I get the error message 'Encountered "MID ( email1 ,. Incorrect conditional expression, Expected one of [like|null|between|in|comparison] condition,'.

I would be very grateful for any help on finding something that works!  Thanks for your help!

Comment: Can you trim the field and use the right x characters?

Comment: Access doesnt support `like` i dont think, but it does support wildcards.  Why not something like `where email_address = %comcast.net`  or if it does support `like`, `where email_address like '%comcast.net'`

Comment: Access does support `like`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [`right()`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/right.php) function to accomplish this. If you didn't strip trailing whitespace when you put it into the database you can use the [`trim`](http://www.techonthenet.com/access/functions/string/trim.php) function as well

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="membership">
  SELECT email_address
  FROM tblMembers
  WHERE right(email_address, 11) = 'comcast.net'
</cfquery>
```

You could also use the [`like`](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/like-operator-HP001032253.aspx) operator, but it's very likely the above option is faster.

```
<cfquery name="test" datasource="membership">
  SELECT email_address
  FROM tblMembers
  WHERE email_address LIKE '*comcast.net'
</cfquery>
```

Also make sure you're using [`cfqueryparam`](https://wikidocs.adobe.com/wiki/display/coldfusionen/cfqueryparam) for all your values if they're something the user is supplying.

Comment: Why do you think right() is faster than like?  Also, query parameters have benfits even when the data is not coming from a user.